# How to turn date format to YYYYMMDD format in Hive QL

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hive, hiveql

In PostgreSQL I can just use:

```
to_char(current_date - 14, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

However this is not an accepted syntax in Hive and I can't find what the proper function is for this date format.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Hive version >= 1.2.0 you can use [date_format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) function. Also `date_sub` function is available:

```
date_format(date_sub(current_date,14),'yyyyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 2):

In Hive, you would typically use an intermediate conversion to a unix timestamp:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp() - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

`unix_timestamp()` returns the current date/time as an epoch timestamp; you can then substract 14 days (expressed as seconds), then use `from_unixtime()` to format the result as a string in the target format.